# Keyboard gets dismissed when tapping into UIWebViews

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, uiwebview

I have some UIWebViews that I am using for rich text editing. They have a div that is contentEditable. The problem is that when switching between fields, the keyboard will get dismissed for a split second if the user taps into a UIWebView.

Going from UIWebView to native UITextView, the keyboard remains displayed.

The keyboard also gets dismissed even when tapping a UIWebView that is *not* contentEditable. In this case, I could turn `userInteractionEnabled` to `false`, but that still wouldn't work if I want it to be scrollable.

Here is a gif demonstrating the problem:

[image: UIWebView Keyboard Dismissal]

There is nothing special code going on behind this, except loading the following HTML into the UIWebViews (contentEditable being removed for the 2nd one)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="editor" contentEditable="true"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: it is nature of iOS. So, what is the problem

Comment: The problem is that when you go between native elements (ie UITextView to UITextView, or UITextField), the keyboard is not dismissed, but it does in this case. So when going into a UIWebView, it goes against the nature of iOS (from a user perspective).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, after scrounging the internet for a week for this and related problems, I ended up finding a duplicate question! I'm reposting the relevant code from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18031231/how-to-avoid-keyboard-hide-show-when-focus-changes-from-uitextfield-and-uiwebv) by [diegoreymendez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712306/diegoreymendez).

UIWebView+GUIFixes.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIWebView (GUIFixes)

/**
 *  @brief      Wether the UIWebView will use the fixes provided by this category or not.
 */
@property (nonatomic, assign, readwrite) BOOL usesGUIFixes;

@end
```

UIWebView+GUIFixes.m

```
#import "UIWebView+GUIFixes.h"
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@implementation UIWebView (GUIFixes)

static const char* const fixedClassName = "UIWebBrowserViewMinusAccessoryView";
static Class fixClass = Nil;

- (UIView *)browserView
{
    UIScrollView *scrollView = self.scrollView;

    UIView *browserView = nil;
    for (UIView *subview in scrollView.subviews) {
        if ([NSStringFromClass([subview class]) hasPrefix:@"UIWebBrowserView"]) {
            browserView = subview;
            break;
        }
    }

    return browserView;
}

- (BOOL)delayedBecomeFirstResponder
{
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.01 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [super becomeFirstResponder];
    });

    return YES;
}

- (void)ensureFixedSubclassExistsOfBrowserViewClass:(Class)browserViewClass
{
    if (!fixClass) {
        Class newClass = objc_allocateClassPair(browserViewClass, fixedClassName, 0);
        objc_registerClassPair(newClass);

        IMP delayedFirstResponderImp = [self methodForSelector:@selector(delayedBecomeFirstResponder)];
        Method becomeFirstResponderMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(browserViewClass, @selector(becomeFirstResponder));
        method_setImplementation(becomeFirstResponderMethod, delayedFirstResponderImp);

        fixClass = newClass;
    }
}

- (BOOL)usesGUIFixes
{
    UIView *browserView = [self browserView];
    return [browserView class] == fixClass;
}

- (void)setUsesGUIFixes:(BOOL)value
{
    UIView *browserView = [self browserView];
    if (browserView == nil) {
        return;
    }

    [self ensureFixedSubclassExistsOfBrowserViewClass:[browserView class]];

    if (value) {
        object_setClass(browserView, fixClass);
    }
    else {
        Class normalClass = objc_getClass("UIWebBrowserView");
        object_setClass(browserView, normalClass);
    }

    [browserView reloadInputViews];
}

@end
```

It feels dirty and fragile having to deal with the objc runtime like this, but as far as I've found, its the only way that actually works.

Comment: We ended up not using this, however. Not only is it super hacky, but there's also a big problem when dealing with languages with multi-stage input (eg. Japanese). You cannot programmatically set it to be the first responder and have text input work correctly.

Comment: What did you end up doing?

Comment: I don't really remember. I don't think we ever really fixed it 100%. Looking at it now, the problem is still there :/

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know keyboard is dismissed when it stops being the first responder. You can use the `...shouldEndEditing:` method, making it returning NO to keep the keyboard visible.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but my problem is more about going between UIWebViews. UIWebViewDelegate doesn't have `...shouldEndEditing:` unfortunately...